# REACT - .map make props as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm encountering an issue with props and .map method (see code below)

I'm passing a props into this grandchild component (an array of 2 objects)! On the React dev tools, my props is passing well. But once, I'm trying to handle the array with a .map method to display the content, I get this issue -> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I have verified many settings but nothing that permit to get over it

Thanks in advance,

Paul

```
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks.map((track) => {
          return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Comment: Simple add default value `const { tracks = [] } = this.props, ..... (tracks.map)...`, you don't need to add any extra checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your render method.

```
 {this.props.tracks.map((track) => {
      return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />;
    })}
```

Instead of the above code your code should look like this,

```
{this.props.tracks && this.props.tracks.length > 0 && this.props.tracks.map((track) => {
          return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />;
        })}
```

Comment: thanks Sabbir, it is working :) But I can't understand why, your condition say "if tracks is true AND tracks higher than 0 THEN .map" What is the magic that permit tracks to be readable by the .map method then ? In other word, why this way tracks get defined ?

Comment: You console log this.props.tracks in the render method you will see why we need to check these. In most of the cases the props we are passing are coming from another component. That is why at first it is undefined and after the actual props is passed it gets the value and renders.

Comment: You can only call `map()` on iterables.  `this.props.tracks` checks that it is not `undefined`   `this.props.tracks.length > 0` checks that it is iterable AND has more than 0 items.  Checking that it is greater than zero may not be necessary for your component, and simply `this.props.tracks.length` may be sufficient.

Comment: I understand better, thank you both to clarify this point!

Comment: @heez, actually > 0 check is necessary because in case length is 0 it will be falsy.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `this.props.tracks` is `undefined` at the time the component is rendered.  You'll have to add some sort of existence check to your `render()` function:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.tracks) {
    return ( /* JSX view for when tracks are undefined */ );
  }

  return ( /* your .map code here */ );
}
```

You can also provide a default value to `this.props.tracks` of `[]` using `prop-types`.  You can read more about [type-checking with PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) on React's official site.

Comment: thanks heez for your response, I have tried the Sabbir solution (below) and it is working

Comment: Nice. I highly recommend using PropTypes to typecheck your props you pass to the component than littering your render functions with `undefined` and `null` existence checks.